# plot lm in R: Error atomic vectors

Tags: r, plot, operators, atomic, lm

I have this regression model:

```
U_IQ_p8 <- lm(adjm ~ Score_IQ5, data= U_IQ_8)
```

Everything worked fine, until I wanted to plot for the Residual analysis:

```
plot(U_IQ_8)
```

**This gives the error:
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

I searched for this and found a related question the problem seems to be with the QQPlot. Indeed, this works:

```
  plot(U_IQ_8, which=1)
```

But I absolutely don´t know how to solve this problem, because I need the whole Residual analysis and I don´t fully understand what´s the problem in my code (especially as I cannot simply change the naming of the variables!)

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Try using `U_IQ_p8["adjm"]` and `U_IQ_p8["Score_UQ5"]` instead

Comment: You should give more info on the `U_IQ_p8` object. What does e.g. `summary(U_IQ_p8)` give you?

Comment: Sorry, I saw that there was one mistake in my Code above, I´ve corrected it. So what you now see is the latest version I´ve tried. Unfortunately, your suggestion does not work. When I do str(U_IQ_8) this is a cut of the output: data.frame': 97 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ number     :Classes 'labelled', 'numeric'  atomic [1:97] 2 13 20 ... 5 other variables (including adjm) look nearly the same. But Score is num [1:97, 1] instead of atomic..

Comment: I wish I could help, but I don't have access to your data and can't investigate it. You should try recreating this problem using data that is available for everyone. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information on how to make good example code.

Comment: Thank you! As this is sensible data, I cannot simply post it. But I tried to recreating it, and thereby I also removed the labels. I imported the data from SPSS and used the Hmisc package to label the columns. When I don´t do it, plot gives no error in the lm! Do you have an idea what could be the problem with it?

Comment: I don't know. The `$` operator is only valid for recursive objects. I suspect `qqplot` calls `$` on the object at some point, but I don't know how to fix it unless I know more about the data. Sorry.

Comment: You _could_ try `as.data.frame(Score_IQ5)` before you call `lm`

Comment: Would you be OK with `par(mfrow=c(2,2)); 
for(i in 1:4) { plot(Model, which=i) }`  ?